# plist editor simple on mac which works on double click

Tags: macos

I really love it when I have to apply some registries on my Windows I just have to double-click on a .reg file

Is there a similar thing on Mac

Comment: A plist is just a plaintext file. You can open it in anything. You ca't do any equivalent of 'load it into the registry' because the Mac has nothing even vaguely similar to the concept of a registry.